# How to set up a cron job to send reminder e-mails in official Redmine Docker image?

Tags: docker, cron, redmine

In a Redmine container based on an [official image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine), I am trying to set up a cron job to send reminder e-mails periodically.

As instructed [here](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/redminereminderemails), typing `bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV=production` as `root` inside the container works fine. However, setting the same command using `crontab -e` does not work and outputs various error messages. I suspect that they have something to do with setting correct `PATH` for Bundler or rake, but not being familiar with Ruby apps I am totally lost right now. I even tried adding (seemingly) relevant environment variables to `crontab` such that:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bundle/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
RUBY_MAJOR=2.6
RUBY_VERSION=2.6.5
RUBY_DOWNLOAD_SHA256=d5d6da717fd48524596f9b78ac5a2eeb9691753da5c06923a6c31190abe01a62
GEM_HOME=/usr/local/bundle
BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING=1
BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=/usr/local/bundle
RAILS_ENV=production
HOME=/home/redmine
REDMINE_VERSION=4.1.0
```

but so far to no avail.

The followings are what I've tried adding on `crontab -e` so far. Each commands are (of course) preceded by cron's date time string format, and trailed by `> /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1` to log whatever it outputs.

- `root cd /usr/src/redmine; bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV=production`
- `root cd /usr/src/redmine; /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV=production`

> `Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

- `cd /usr/src/redmine; /usr/local/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV=production`
- `/usr/src/redmine/remind.sh` (The following script)

`remind.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/src/redmine
bundle exec /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake redmine:send_reminders days=7 RAILS_ENV="production"
```

> ```
> bundler: failed to load command: /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake
> (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rake) Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find
> rake-13.0.1 in any of the sources  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in
> materialize'   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `map!'   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `materialize'   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in
> `specs'   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in
> `specs_for'   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in
> `requested_specs'  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in
> definition_method'  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require'  
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
> `require'
> ```

- `root cd /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake; rake --trace redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV=production`

> ```
> rake aborted! No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile,
> rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:698:in
> `raw_load_rakefile'
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in
> `block in load_rakefile'
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in
> `load_rakefile'
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in
> `block in run'
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in
> `standard_exception_handling'
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in
> `run' /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in
> `<top (required)>' /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:23:in `load'
> /usr/local/bundle/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
> ```

Here is what is inside `/usr/src/redmine`. A file named `Gemfile` exists.

```
root@975094a2b06b:/usr/src/redmine# ls -l
total 140
-rw-rw-r--  1 redmine redmine  538 Dec 20  2019 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-rw-r--  1 redmine redmine 2937 Dec 20  2019 Gemfile
-rw-rw-rw-  1 redmine redmine 5665 Apr 21  2020 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    5491 Feb 27  2020 Gemfile.lock.mysql2
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    5483 Feb 27  2020 Gemfile.lock.postgresql
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    5493 Feb 27  2020 Gemfile.lock.sqlite3
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root    5645 Feb 27  2020 Gemfile.lock.sqlserver
-rw-rw-r--  1 redmine redmine  205 Dec 20  2019 README.rdoc
-rwxrwxr-x  1 redmine redmine  275 Dec 20  2019 Rakefile
drwxrwxr-x  6 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 app
-rw-rw-r--  1 redmine redmine  863 Dec 20  2019 appveyor.yml
drwxrwxr-x  2 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 bin
drwxr-xr-x  1 redmine redmine 4096 Mar 26  2020 config
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root     136 Mar 10  2020 config.ru
drwxrwxrwx  1 redmine redmine 4096 Mar 26  2020 db
drwxrwxr-x  2 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 doc
drwxrwxr-x  5 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 extra
drwxr-xr-x  3 redmine redmine 4096 Oct 19 10:16 files
drwxrwxr-x  6 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 redmine redmine 4096 Mar 18  2020 log
drwxr-xr-x  5 redmine redmine 4096 Mar 26  2020 plugins
drwxrwxr-x  1 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 public
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root     125 Dec 17 16:24 remind.sh
drwxrwxrwx  2 redmine redmine 4096 Feb 27  2020 sqlite
drwxrwxr-x 14 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 test
drwxr-xr-x  1 redmine redmine 4096 Feb 27  2020 tmp
drwxrwxr-x  2 redmine redmine 4096 Dec 20  2019 vendor
```

What is the correct command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that **crond** included in **BusyBox** could run `bundle exec rake...` command without a problem. Perhaps it handles environment variables differently from standard crond?

All I had to do was

```
apt-get install busybox-static
busybox crontab -e
```

and then adding following job to crontab's list.

```
0 7 * * 1-5 cd /usr/src/redmine; bundle exec rake redmine:send_reminders RAILS_ENV=production
```

Please note that, for the time being, those steps were done manually inside the running Redmine container. I will add these to `Dockerfile` later.